# corel problem help needed

Tags: corel-draw, windows-7

I recently had a problem, I caught the virus. The virus has damaged many files fortunately most of them games. But suffered a couple of sketches needed for my work. They do not open. Sketches made in CorelDRAW X4. How to get them back in working condition? Is there such a way?

Comment: I would say that if CorelDRAW doesn't suggest a fix to you then it's very unlikely that you'll be able to recover them. Have you tried [getting in touch with Corel](http://www.corel.com/us/support/)?

Comment: hey @giannijimenez and welcome to GD.SE :)  you might be able to get better help over in [Super User](http://superuser.com/) — that's where the computer wizards hang out

Answer (score 1):

For a file to open correctly in any program, the program needs to recognize the file format. If a virus has corrupted the file, important information about the file and its format might have gone missing. The only way to make it open again is to restore that information.

There are programs out there that can recognize some formats based on contents and make them openable again and I have used such programs to save both image files and music files, but in most cases I have suffered some content loss. If there are restoration programs that can restore CorelDRAW files, I do not know. But you can try googling for data recovery software and see if there is one that can restore CorelDRAW files.

Apart from this, the only thing you can really do is just to mourn the loss of your files and check up on different solutions for backing up your data.

Comment: Hi Szandor, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!